# Is there a website that lists last minute opportunities?

Tags: budget, flight-search-engines, short-notice

Are there any websites that list last minute travel opportunities? either just flights or flights with travel packs (hotel, etc).

I have total freedom and I am situated in Europe.

A couple of airlines companies I knew used to do this.   They would sell their empty seats, cheaper, last minute. I don't think this happens any more. Does it?

Unfortunately googling is not too effective since "last minute" is a very common word to sell. Maybe some expert information will be more effective.

Comment: [BA do Hello Weekend](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/offers/holidays/helloweekend), is that the sort of thing you're after? Only BA holidays though!

Comment: If you are flexible and have a taste for the adventurous you can try a [blind booking](https://www.germanwings.com/skysales/BlindBooking.aspx?culture=en-GB)

Comment: Also, you can read [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50197/where-to-find-ferry-flights-and-empty-leg-flights) for an interesting change-of-pace

Answer (score 9):

I'd try priceline and do it during the week, not on a weekend. http://www.priceline.com/promo/name_your_own_price/flights/

Comment: How does that work? I tried it, but in the end it asks to pay. I though those were last minute oportunities.

Comment: so you are looking for something where you don't have to pay?

Comment: Why not on weekends?

Answer (score 2):

The current second PWSE result for the title of this question is: [lastminute.com](http://www.lastminute.com).

The first is this question.

[image: lmgtfy]

Comment: Sorry, what's PWSE ?

Comment: Seconding @Blackbird57, SE usually denotes Stack Exchange, but what's PW?

Comment: I'm thirding this.

Comment: Guessing SE means 'search engine' in this context. No idea what PW is.

Comment: maybe Price Watch?

Comment: I'd upvote if I knew what PWSE is.  The mighty google is no help. *"Professional Wrestling Simulator Enthusiast"*???

Comment: Popular Web Search Engine, i.e. Google.

Comment: Anyway, OP didn't do any research before asking the question.

Comment: Last Minute used to do good last minute deals, but these days they seem to have morphed into just another boring old OTA

Comment: @OrangeDog I did some research, but "last minute travel opportunities" is definitly a very appetizing search term for blogs and travel agencies. In other words, you get lots of unwanted stuff. Some "inside knowledge" or expert knowledge, like the one provided here, might give way better results.

Comment: @Gagravarr oh that's a shame, I haven't used them for a while

Comment: Yes, despite being called "LastMinute" they have for years just been another travel agent. Also, google search results are very, very  customized. The result order for you is not the same as for everybody else - possibly not even the same as if you used a different browser.