# How long does it take for Priceline to process Last Minute ticket requests?

Tags: air-travel, short-notice

Based on [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50758/is-there-a-website-that-lists-last-minute-opportunities) I discovered Priceline's [Last Minute offers](http://www.priceline.com/promo/lastminute/). You need to pay for it in advance though.

The process is a bit fuzzy and there are obviously no guarantees. Assuming I "request" a travel for the next week when do I get an answer? Is it possible to cancel my request before I get a result?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out too. I would like to know when they will get back to me, and if I have the option to cancel the request (before they find a match) if I find a good deal I like on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So [I tweeted the source, Priceline](https://twitter.com/marksmayo/status/643604665855152128) to ask them.  They [just responded](https://twitter.com/priceline/status/643770380004536320), with:

> Once you place an offer we search for a travel partner willing to
>   accept your bid. You should get a response w/n 20 minutes.

So you only have to wait around 20 minutes to know whether or not you should go looking for something else.